# Set image control source in view model Wpf

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have a view that contains an image control that is binded to this property:

```
   private System.Drawing.Image _sigImage;
    public System.Drawing.Image sigImage
    {
        get { return _sigImage; }
        set { _sigImage = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
    }
```

I am busy implementing a a signature pad using mvvm, and want the signature to display in the image control. However i cant get it to display.

The code for die signature pad is:

```
  DynamicCapture dc = new DynamicCaptureClass();
        DynamicCaptureResult res = dc.Capture(sigCtl, "Who", "Why", null, null);
        if (res == DynamicCaptureResult.DynCaptOK)
        {

            sigObj = (SigObj)sigCtl.Signature;
            sigObj.set_ExtraData("AdditionalData", "C# test: Additional data");

            try
            {
                byte[] binaryData = sigObj.RenderBitmap("sign", 200, 150, "image/png", 0.5f, 0xff0000, 0xffffff, 10.0f, 10.0f, RBFlags.RenderOutputBinary | RBFlags.RenderColor32BPP) as byte[];
                using (MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream(binaryData))
                {
                    System.Drawing.Image newImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(memStream);

                    sigImage = newImage;

                    // work with image here. 
                    // You'll need to keep the MemoryStream open for 
                    // as long as you want to work with your new image. 
                    memStream.Dispose();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

The image is stored as a bitmap in the variable newImage.

How can i bind that image to the image control of sigImage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.Drawing.Image` is not an appropriate type for the `Source` property of an Image element. It is WinForms, not WPF.

Use `System.Windows.Media.ImageSource` instead

```
private ImageSource sigImage;

public ImageSource SigImage
{
    get { return sigImage; }
    set { sigImage = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
}
```

and assign a BitmapImage or BitmapFrame to the property, which is directly created from the MemoryStream. `BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad` has to be set in order to enable closing the stream immediately after decoding the bitmap.

```
var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();

using (var memStream = new MemoryStream(binaryData))
{
    bitmapImage.BeginInit();
    bitmapImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
    bitmapImage.StreamSource = memStream;
    bitmapImage.EndInit();
}

bitmapImage.Freeze();
SigImage = bitmapImage;
```

The Binding would look like shown below, provided an instance of the class with the `SigImage` property is assigned to the DataContext of the view.

```
<Image Source="{Binding SigImage}"/>
```

---

Since WPF has built-in type conversion from `string`, `Uri` and `byte[]` to `ImageSource`, you may as well declare the source property as `byte[]`

```
private byte[] sigImage;

public byte[] SigImage
{
    get { return sigImage; }
    set { sigImage = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
}
```

and assign a value like

```
SigImage = binaryData;
```

without manually creating a BitmapImage or BitmapFrame, or changing the Binding.